# Identify KB2468871v2 .net patch installation

Tags: .net, batch-file, cmd

I 'am looking for a reliable method for detecting the existence of KB2468871v2 on a target system. If it hasn't been installed a function of the software I work with doesn't work. When I am installing on site, as part of a scripted install, I like to preload it where it's missing to assist the client in avoiding error's etc.

Recently I have been working in an area where IT policy has blocked regedit queries by policy even though I have admin rights to install the software. This has broken my previous working reg query script which worked fine to detect it's presence there, then install or skip as required.

I am now working on a NON reg query solution to get round the problem but am finding it is unreliable. After trying to find the presence of a folder somewhere deep in the OS to achieve this, I am using this handy exe from here http://www.asoft.be/prod_netver.html to parse the .net set up info into a text file. Then using a find command to search for the KB2468871v2 entry & if exist omit the patch install and carry on the script or if it's not present, choose the 64 or 32 bit version of the patch appropriately.

The problem is the file fails to log the fact it is installed, trips the installer where its not needed. It works fine where the text does get populated with the What I could with is something, with out using the reg, tell me if KB2468871v2 is installed on PC or not. The code contains some variables for logging purposes and winbit is set by a line further up the page.

Hope that makes sense, thanks for any info....

I have tried a wmic command that lists all the updates on a PC but it doesn't list .net patches, some thing like that would ideal if it did.

```
:KB2468871
CLS
echo.
echo      :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
echo      ::                  -- KB2468871 Update Check --                   ::
echo      :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
echo.
(ping -n 3 127.0.0.1>nul)
dotnet.exe C:\Temp\Microsoft_Net.txt /extended
findstr /C:"KB2468871v2" C:\Temp\Microsoft_Net.txt >nul
if %errorlevel% == 0 (echo KB2468871 Okay >> %log% & echo KB2468871 Okay & goto install) ELSE (goto patchnet)

:patchnet
CLS
echo.
echo      :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
echo      ::                     -- KB2468871 Required --                    ::
echo      :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
echo.
IF %winbit%==x64 (echo 64_KB2468871 Needed >> %log% & echo 64_KB2468871 Needed & "NDP40-KB2468871-v2-x64.exe" /norestart /quiet) ELSE (
echo 32_KB2468871 Needed >> %log% & echo 32_KB2468871 Needed & "NDP40-KB2468871-v2-x86.exe" /norestart /quiet)
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: can you install hotfixes if you're refrained from using regedit?

Comment: Yes seems okay I can install manually but when ever reg query comes up get error about being blocked or equivalent

Comment: You need to show us your current code, we cannot be expected to formulate responses which can be incorporated into something we've never seen. Additionally, in order to prevent responses offering potential solutions which use methods which may also be blocked, could you please provide a list of things which are known to be and not to be blocked. Do not attempt to add any of that information in a comment, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51060314/edit) to do so, _remembering to format your code using the `{}` button_.

Comment: The biggest problem is what will you do if KB2468871v2 is superseded (or included) by (in) another differently numbered path.